# Renaming + moving the compiled python exe issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, exe

```
def move_me():
if os.path.isfile(os.path.normpath(r"%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\system.exe")) is False:
    shutil.move("gg.exe", os.path.normpath(r"%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\system.exe"))
```

hi, I am new to python...
what's wrong with the code?

gg.exe is this code itself
when I run it, it should be moved to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup and be renamed to system.exe
but it did not work...

Comment: Which error is being thrown?

Comment: it does not throw an error, it just isn't moving and renaming the file ...

Comment: You have a `%s` which is used for string formatting but then you don't actually do string formatting, so a literal "%s" ends up at the front of that path. What do you want to be there?

Comment: [Yes](https://www.learnpython.org/en/String_Formatting), you have to add a `%` followed by the text you want to be instead of `%s`.

Comment: idk, I just saw someone uses it:

Comment: like that - os.path.isfile(os.path.normpath(r"%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\system.exe"%)) 
??

Comment: In Windows, `%APPDATA%` holds the application data path (which might not be in the Roaming directory). Does this work for you? `system_exe =  os.path.normpath("{APPDATA}/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/system.exe".format(**os.environ))` and then use that variable for the test can move.

Comment: You could also do `os.path.expandvars("%APPPATH%/Microsoft/Windows.Start Menu/Progams/...")`. Note the two %'s, no "Roaming" and these days forward slashes work with windows paths.

Comment: it worked thx - tdelaney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show you all the environment variables

```py
print(os.environ.keys())
```

and

```
>>> os.environ['APPDATA']
'AppData\Roaming'
```

Then you can rewrite your function as:

```py
def move_me():
    filename = "gg.exe"
    fullpath = os.path.normpath("{APPDATA}\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\system.exe".format(**os.environ))
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath) is False:
        shutil.move(filename, fullpath)
```